# Animating a swap of cells in a table on click using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to make a simple flash-card game in JavaScript using JQuery. In one part of the game, you should click on a row in a "table" (`tablica`) made out of `div`s (`tablica[i][j]`) to swap the cells in that row (to put the content in the cell in the correct column). Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
for (var j=0; j<odgovor1.length; j++)
            for (var i=1; i<3; i++)
            {
                tablica[i][j]=document.createElement("div");
                tablica[i][j].setAttribute("class","rijecUDrugomDijelu");
                if (i===1) tablica[i][j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(odgovor1[j]));
                else if (i===2) tablica[i][j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(odgovor2[j]));
                tablica[i][j].style.top=228+27*j;
                tablica[i][j].style.left=-153+110+153*i;
                tablica[i][j].onclick=eval(
                        "(function()"+
                        "{"+
                        "var tmp=tablica[1]["+j+"].style.left;"+
                        "tablica[1]["+j+"].style.left=tablica[2]["+j+"].style.left;"+
                        "tablica[2]["+j+"].style.left=tmp;"+
                        "tmp=odgovor1["+j+"];"+
                        "odgovor1["+j+"]=odgovor2["+j+"];"+
                        "odgovor2["+j+"]=tmp;"+
                        "})"
                        );
                pozadina.appendChild(tablica[i][j]);
            }
```

When the user clicks on a row in that table, the cells in that row are swapped, and the content of the table is correctly tracked in the string arrays `odgovor1` and `odgovor2`. However, they are swapped without any animation, they are swapped immediately. When I try to apply JQuery animations to the cells (`div`s) `tablica[1][j]` and `tablica[2][j]`, the program crashes. Do you know how to do that properly?
Again, I assure you, the code above works well now, but when I try to use JQuery animations instead of simply swapping the properties `style.left`, it crashes.

Comment: Why in the name of all that's holy are you using `eval()` for that function handler? Never use `eval()`. Your code should look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vxbnn9ee/. With regard to your issue, you cannot animate table cells reliably as it breaks the table layout mid-transition.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 1. I can't open your link. 2. eval() is safe as long as there is no danger of it executing arbitrary code. 3. I am not using a table at all. The divs are **arranged** like a table.

Comment: 2. Safety is an issue, but eval is awful practice, not to mention slow, and there is absolutely no excuse for using it. Especially in cases like this when there is no need. 3. Then please show us your HTML. We can't fix something we can't see

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The code is 850 lines. I can't see why the for-loop in which the divs are created is relevant here.

Comment: Then create a sample of it. It's completely relevant because you could have the HTML setup in an innumerable number of ways which would affect the logic you need to use. I'd suggest you read about [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes" here? What crashes? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Using object properties instead of `eval` appears to work:

```
for (var j=0; j<odgovor1.length; j++)
            for (var i=1; i<3; i++)
                    {
                    tablica[i][j]=document.createElement("div");
                    tablica[i][j].setAttribute("class","rijecUDrugomDijelu");
                    if (i===1) tablica[i][j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(odgovor1[j]));
                    else if (i===2) tablica[i][j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(odgovor2[j]));
                    tablica[i][j].style.top=228+27*j;
                    tablica[i][j].style.left=-153+110+153*i;
                    tablica[i][j].redak=j;
                    tablica[i][j].onclick=
                            function()
                            {
                            var tmp=tablica[1][this.redak].style.left;
                            $(tablica[1][this.redak]).animate({left:(tablica[2][this.redak].style.left)},500);
                            $(tablica[2][this.redak]).animate({left:(tmp)},500);
                            tmp=odgovor1[this.redak];
                            odgovor1[this.redak]=odgovor2[this.redak];
                            odgovor2[this.redak]=tmp;
                            }
                    pozadina.appendChild(tablica[i][j]);
                    }
```